# What is replacing .then(data => console.log(data)) with just .then(console.log) called?

Tags: javascript

I saw the following code in a React application.

```
getData()
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(console.log)
```

And it behaves exactly the same as I would use

```
getAllStudents()
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
```

So in the first example the called function `console.log` somehow implicitly knows it should take the data as parameter and show it in the console. That function is not even called with `console.log()`

Could you please tell me what this shortcut concept is called? I would like to read more about it, but I don't know how exactly I should use it.

Comment: `.then` expects a function as parameter and `console.log` is a function. `data => console.log(data)` is also a function.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a name for the concept of not wrapping a function call in an anonymous function.

Comment: You give it a reference to a function and it calls the function. No different than `.then(myFunction)` and `function myFunction(data) { }`

Comment: Be aware that even though those two examples behave similarly in this specific case, there can be behavioral differences. If the console.log method referred to "this" for example, it would be bound to a different object in these two instances. Also if there were an error thrown inside console.log, the stack trace would omit the first code, but it would include the second one.

Comment: Thank you @StriplingWarrior for further details!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called "point free style" or tacit programming.

See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming

**Edit:** The above case may not exactly be tacit programming, as that involves defining functions without explicitly mentioning their arguments ("tacit" = "implicit"), and here you are merely using an already defined function as an argument. But a function definition

```
const log = console.log
```

would be a tacit function, as opposed to

```
const log = data => console.log(data)
```

so the concept is at least closely related to the difference in the question.

Comment: `Could you please tell me what this shortcut concept is called?` If the question is what it's called, then this answer seems spot on to me.

Comment: I read the article and another one on Tacit Programming and it seems to me this is correct. Thank you for this new knowledge :)

Comment: I do appreciate your sharing this article because I'd never heard of Tacit Programming before, and I enjoyed learning about it. But I'm not sure it's quite what's being described in the question. Tacit programming applied in JavaScript would be more like what RxJS has done with the `pipe()` function: you pass transforms in as arguments to a piping chain/operator/function.

Comment: Thank you Andreas for the, that is what I was searching for :)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior yes, the code in question is not *exactly* tacit programming - but though function composition is an integral part of tacit programming, the "tacit" part refers mainly to omitting the function arguments when defining functions. I edited my answer to clarify that.